# AngularJS: 1 json-file displayed and 1 not after implementing routing

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to learn AngularJS. I'm trying to implement routing with $routeProvider and have successfully managed to implement it. But now my data won't get loaded. I had a controller that loaded 2 json-files and they worked great before I implemented the routing. Now, 1 set gets loaded and the other isn't. The attributes get displayed at the screen without any trouble but the rooms don't get displayed. Here is my code:

app.js:

```
'use strict';

var schoolApp = angular.module('schoolApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'schoolController'
]);

schoolApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/list', {
          templateUrl: 'view/list.html',
          controller: 'schoolController'
        }).
        when('/platform', {
          templateUrl: 'view/platform.html',
          controller: 'schoolController'
        }).
        otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/'
        });
  }]);
```

controller.js:

```
var schoolController = angular.module('schoolController', ['ngRoute']);

schoolController.controller('schoolController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('data/1stfloor.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.rooms = data;
    });
}]);
```

index.html:

```
<html ng-app="schoolApp" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="SchoolController">
        <a href="#/list"><img class="icon" ng-src="img/icon/list.png"/></a>
        <a href="#/platform"><img class="icon" ng-src="img/icon/platform.png"/></a><br/>

        <div>
            <ng-view>

            </ng-view>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

platform.html:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="room in rooms">
        <span>{{room.naam}}</span>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Edit: I get an error that looks like this:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Tb (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js:14:147)
    at e.defaults.transformResponse (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js:63:45)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js:62:337
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at q (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js:7:255)
    at mc (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js:62:319)
    at c (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js:63:494)
    at C (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js:91:187)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js:92:350
angular.js:9228     
(anonymous function)
angular.js:6781 
(anonymous function)
angular.js:10728 
Cangular.js:10811 
(anonymous function)
angular.js:11726 
h.$evalangular.js:11554 
h.$digesthint.js:1468 
scopePrototype.$digestangular.js:11832 
h.$applyhint.js:1478 
scopePrototype.$applyangular.js:7774 
fangular.js:7947 
Kangular.js:7903 
y.onreadystatechange
```

Edit:
I have left everything out so I only have a repeat which displays only the rooms and I still get the same error. Unexpected token ]. I editted the code above to how it is now.

Solution:
It turns out I had a misplaced comma in my json-file. Thanks for the decent feedback I got from the stacktrace of javascript, I just spent hours finding out that my error didn't have anything to do with my javascript.. Nice...

Comment: please remove angular-ui-router tag.

Comment: Any error in console? Sure you json is not empty?

Comment: I am sure that the json is not empty. I do get one error but I don't know what this could be. I will add this as edit to my question

Comment: @MaartenMeeusen inside inner ng-repeat why you use {{room.attributes[$index]}}? why you don't use attr directly?

Comment: @MaartenMeeusen If You want parent $index in that then do $paren.$index.because ng-repeat everytime create a new scope.

Comment: I have left the $index out and still have the same error.. Does it maybe have something to do with the dependencies I inject or something?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is in this line of HTML

```
<img class="icon" ng-src="./img/icon/{{room.attributes[$index]}}.png"/>
```

Why room.attributes[$index]? 'attr' should be good enough. If you want to access the parent index(i.e., room index), you need to use $parent.

Assuming you are having attributes in each room, if not the inner ng-repeat might not work.

Answer (score 0):

### Try below code:

### 1. Controller code

```
var schoolCtrl = angular.module('SchoolController', ['ngRoute']);

schoolCtrl.controller('SchoolController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.initList = function(){
      $http.get('data/attributes.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.attributes = data;
      });
    }

    $scope.initPlatformList = function(){
      $http.get('data/1stfloor.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.rooms = data;
      }); 
    }

}]);
```

### 2. list.html

```
<div ng-init="initList()">
   ...
</div>
```

### 3. platform.html

```
<div ng-init="initPlatformList()">
   ...
</div>
```

Try it, should work.

In your given code, it seems that scope is not getting refresh.

### Edit

### Working code:

### index.html

```
<html ng-app="schoolApp" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>

        <script src="controller.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="SchoolController">
        <a href="#/list">List</a>
        <a href="#/platform">Platform</a><br/>

        <div>
            <ng-view>

            </ng-view>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

### controller.js

```
var schoolCtrl = angular.module('SchoolController', ['ngRoute']);

schoolCtrl.controller('SchoolController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('http://localhost:8080/getAttributes').success(function(data) {
        $scope.attributes = data;
    });

    $http.get('http://localhost:8080/getList').success(function(data) {
        $scope.rooms = data;
    });
}]);
```

For testing purpose i am hitting my server.

### attributes.json

```
[
{
"beschrijving": "XYZ"
},
{
"beschrijving": "ABC"
}
]
```

### 1stfloor.json

```
[
{
"name": "Tajmahal Delux",
"capacity": 10
},
{
"name": "Hayat India",
"capacity": 5
}
]
```

Rest of the code is same as you have used.

Try it, will help you.

Comment: I got your problem, you must wrap attribute names in double quotes("") which i believe you are missing. This is the only way to specify valid transport JSON, which is stricter than object notation in an executable JavaScript context. Any JSON parser will fail if you try to use the more lax notation. I have updated the above code, refer Edit section to let your code run.

Comment: You're answer got me thinking. It didn't have something to do with the double quotes or something. I examined my json-file and discovered that I had a misplaced comma somewhere in my json. A pretty stupid error. I just spend hours of searching after this because a decent debugger isn't possible for javascript.. Anyway. Thanks for your help, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are assigning same controller 'SchoolController' twice in body as well as using ng-view.
so they are messing with each other, the controller which you have given to body(i.e. parent of your view).
It should be of different name

**controller.js:**

```
//no need to create new module
schoolApp.controller('SchoolController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('data/attributes.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.attributes = data;
    });

    $http.get('data/1stfloor.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.rooms = data;
    });
}]);

schoolApp.controller('parentCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    //write a global stuff or methods here
}]);
```

**HTML**

```
<html ng-app="schoolApp" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular-route.min.js">    </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body ng-controller="parentCtrl">
        <a href="#/list"><img class="icon" ng-src="img/icon/list.png"/></a>
        <a href="#/platform"><img class="icon" ng-src="img/icon/platform.png"/></a><br/>
        <div>
            <ng-view></ng-view>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Try this code. I didn't tested this,
Hope this will be helpful to you.

Comment: And what do I need the parentcontroller for? If i do it like this without the parentcontroller It still is the same..